# Using r to loop and match data

Tags: r, loops

I have uploaded a csv file to r with mostly binary data. What I want to do is manipulate data in column 'b' based on the the corresponding entry in column 'a.'

For example, I would love to loop through my entire dataset and for every row with an entry of '1' in column 2, check to see the entry in column 3 in the same row. Then, find out how many of these successful queries exist.

Similarly, I have several columns of large integers and would love to confirm one of the other binary columns by checking if one of the large numbers is greater than the other. For example, column '3' is the binary result of "Home team wins?" I then have the score of the game in Column "Home team score" and "Away team score." I would really love to create a loop that would see if the entry in 'home team wins' is confirmed by the entry in 'home team score' > 'away team score.'

Thank you

Comment: The merge and match functions would seem be the obvious loop-free methods. You are asked to provide dput output or code to have examples.

Comment: R users usually use vectorized operations instead of loops, because loops in R are slow unless they are very simple. Really all you need here is to sum a boolean expression on your column names (join multiple boolean expressions with `&`). Summing adds `TRUE` as 1 and `FALSE` as 0, and thus the number of matching queries. Edit your question with a sample dataset, and you'll get a more concrete code answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(data.table)
dataset <- data.table(
Homescore = c(2,4,8,0,3,2,3,4),
Awayscore = c(3,2,3,4,2,4,8,0),
Homewin = c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1)
)

NoOfSuccess <- dim(
dataset[Homescore > Awayscore & Homewin == 1]
)[1]

NoOfFailure <- dim(
dataset[Homescore > Awayscore & Homewin == 0]
)[1]

NoOfSuccess
#[1] 2
NoOfFailure
#[1] 2
```

Comment: `dataset[,sum(Homescore > Awayscore & Homewin == 1)]` is more efficient than `nrow(dataset[Homescore > Awayscore & Homewin == 1])`. Why create a potentially large subset result, merely to count its rows?

Comment: @MatthewDowle - I wast trying to be very clear in terms of explaining the thought process. In terms of coding efficiency, you're absolutely right.

Comment: Ah I see. Reading this one again, it's actually quite neat how a new user (Dave) can be set straight so quickly with `data.table` syntax. No suite of 11+ functions to learn, you just stick the logic inside `[]`. It's pretty easy really isn't it :)

Comment: For someone just starting R, `data.table` is really overkill (and a separate syntax). This is really easy to do in base R, anyway.